# Spring Data JPA - How to read entity from jar? - java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Java 15
Spring boot 2.4

Product entity(from spCommon-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar):

```java
package xyz.defe.sp.common.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private double price;
    private int stock;

    public Product() {
        id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }
}
```

ProductDao:

```java
package xyz.defe.sp.spProduct.jpa;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import xyz.defe.sp.common.entity.Product;

@Repository
public interface ProductDao extends JpaRepository<Product, String> {
}
```

Main class:

```java
package xyz.defe.sp.spProduct;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("xyz.defe.sp.spProduct.jpa")
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "xyz.defe.sp.common.entity", "xyz.defe.sp.spProduct.entity" })
public class SpProductApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpProductApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

When run the main method,I got the exception info below:

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2021-01-28 16:22:29.182 ERROR 2800 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'productDao' defined in xyz.defe.sp.spProduct.jpa.ProductDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on SpProductApplication: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class xyz.defe.sp.common.entity.Product
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-5.3.1.jar:5.3.1]

Why the `@EntityScan` annotation isn't work? How to solve it?

Comment: Because you are messing around with dependencies yourself and have included Jakarta  JPA as an API instead of the regular java one. Spring nor Spring Boot supports the Jakarta APIs yet.

Comment: Thanks! I removed 'jakarta.persistence' and added 'javax.persistence',now it working.

Comment: You shouldn't add that, you should use `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` instead of adding dependencies manually. That will prevent future mistakes.

Comment: Thank you,I will replace it with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`.